# Google Sheets multiple query matching words and numbers

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I need to query a sheet in Google Sheets to find matches for multiple words where values are greater than a specified number.

For example, I want to find all words containing 'garden' or 'gate' and the value is greater than '30' in a sheet that looks something like this:

[image]

I have this formula but it's not working:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:B,"select * where A contains 'garden' OR A contains 'gate' AND B>30 ")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:B, 
 "where B > 30 
    and (A contains 'garden' 
     or  A contains 'gate')", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:B, 
 "where A matches '.*garden.*|.*gate.*' 
    and B > 30", 0)
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QOe7e6D_xjaQytoP1sKCCYSAO3rqknRgQv-DfPqBJRY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:B,"where  B > 30 and (A like '%garden%' OR A like '%gate%')")
```