# Google Sheets Query match multiple numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

[This article](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/sql-in-operator-in-google-sheets-query/) explains that SQL IN is not available in Google Query, so it recommends using "matches" separating the parameters with vertical bars, like so: `=QUERY($A$1:$B,"SELECT A WHERE B matches 'Apple|Banana'")`. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56855384/3938636), you can even do partial matches like so: `where A matches '.*apple.*|.*banana.*'`

However, this vertical bar syntax does not seem to work when the source column contains numbers: `=QUERY($A$1:$B,"SELECT A WHERE B matches '17|32'")`.

I've tried (with no luck): `17|32`, `'17'|'32'`, `('17|32')`, `('17'|'32')`.
Then I thought perhaps I could first convert column B to text, but that didn't work either: `text(B) matches '17'`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=QUERY(A1:B,"SELECT A WHERE B matches '.*(17|32).*'")
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the one combination I didn't think of trying - `'17|32'` (although `'(17|32)'` works too):

`=QUERY($A$1:$B,"SELECT A WHERE B matches '17|32'")`